# Простой алгоритм не работает

Tags: c++

**Написал решение тривиальной задачки, но она почему-то не работает. Сколько не тестил, всё хорошо, но 40% проверок на сайте не проходит.**

Условие:
У Витека есть набор кубиков, на котором изображены английские буквы, причём как маленькие, так и большие. Недавно мама подарила ему ещё и набор кубиков с цифрами, в результате чего Витек научился быстро считать в пределах 10-ти. А вот отец имел неосторожность подарить ему набор разноцветных маркеров, после чего Витек начал экспериментировать с кубиками с цифрами: он зарисовывал очередную цифру и на её месте рисовал цифру на единицу большую. Так как он прекрасно понимал, что цифры 10 не существует, он вместо числа 10 всегда писал цифру 0

Учтите, что иногда мама звала Витека покушать и он не успевал завершить начатую работу и написать новую цифру – в этом случае кубик навсегда оставался пустым, такие кубики обозначены символом пробела

Необходимо помочь Витеку и написать программу, которая выполнит очередную маркЕровку кубиков по указанным правилам. Так как Вы находитесь не дома, а на олимпиаде, то мама Вас кушать не позовёт и работу Вам обязательно нужно закончить.

**Входные данные**

Единственная строка, состоящая из описанных выше символов. Длина строки не превышает 255 символов.

**Выходные данные**

Единственная строка – результат работы Вашей программы.

**Примеры првавильных тестов:**

**Входные данные #1**

abc2345678901ABC

**Выходные данные #1**

abc1234567890ABC

**Входные данные #2**

35725yg q69 PD3K65QlO5rGB98A53Y17aUI60Bd74j63xk6

**Выходные данные #2**

46836yg q70 PD4K76QlO6rGB09A64Y28aUI71Bd85j74xk7

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str;
    getline(cin, str);
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        if (str[i] >= 48 and str[i] <= 57)
        {
            if (str[i] == '1' and str[i + 1] == '0')
            {
                cout << '0';
                i += 1;
            }
            else
            { 
                if (str[i] != '9')
                {
                    str[i] += 1;
                    cout << str[i];
                }
                else cout << '0';
            }
        }
        else cout << str[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: В #1 вход с выходом не попутали?

Comment: Вы почему-то в случае, если передано `10` заменяете на `0`. Зачем? Ведь нужно `9` заменять на `0`.

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых, не понятно, как это у автора вообще проходило какие-либо тесты, т.к. ключевого слова `and` в С++ нет.

Во-вторых, для проверки, является ли символ представлением числа, достаточно использовать встроенную функцию `isdigit`, а не перебирать коды символов вручную.

В-третьих, как я уже написал в комментарии, у автора довольно странно сделано вот это:

```cpp
            if (str[i] == '1' and str[i + 1] == '0')
            {
                cout << '0';
                i += 1;
            }
```

Не говоря про `and`, `str[i + 1]` здесь – потенциальный выход за границы (если `i` будет равно последнему элементу массива). И сама логика не ясна. Если данное число равно 1, а следующее 0, нужно вывести 0 и пропустить следующее... Но по условию ведь на 0 нужно заменять 9, а не 10. Здесь вообще не бывает 10, здесь есть только 1 и 0.

В-четвёртых, `str[i] += 1;` возвращает `int`, а значит `cout` выводит код каждого символа числами, а не сами символы, а потому нужно преобразовывать коды обратно в символы.

В общем, принимая во внимание вышесказанное, я бы написал так:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str;
    getline(cin, str);
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        if (isdigit(str[i]))
        {
            if (str[i] != '9')
            {
                cout << static_cast<char>(str[i] + 1);
            }
            else cout << '0';
        }
        else cout << str[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: ```#define and &&``` и ты в шоколаде

Comment: @kleshenki, так можно вообще все операторы `#define`-ами переопределить. Только вот надо ли?

Comment: Это когда автор из паскаля перешел :D #define Begin { и все дела, а так да, конечно не надо

Comment: `т.к. ключевого слова and в С++ нет.` Почему нет, есть.https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical

Comment: есть, есть. просто студия долго это не поддерживала, а gcc вполне себе. Но если студии сказать `/permissive-` или `/Za` и все будет хорошо. Правда другой код может взорваться...

Answer (score 0):

Еще вариант:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string s;
    std::cin >> s;

    for (int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        if (std::isdigit(s[i])) {
            ++s[i];
            if (s[i] == ':') s[i] = '0';
        }
    }

    std::cout << s;
}
```